# VS C# build fails due to missing definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I accidentally double-clicked on a form when I should have just clicked. An event handler was auto-added to my code. I removed it because I don't want any click behavior and now the build is looking for it and fails. How can I undo my double-click? I could just put the empty event handler back but I hate code that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you remove the setting in the properties grid (in the design view) for the form as well?

Comment: Do a search on the `event` shown in your failed build.  Then remove its usage.

Comment: I put the code back in so I could use the context menus "find all references" with the cursor on the method name. That worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with three easy steps :

1. Compile
2. Double click
3. Erase

Compile your solution, this will bring you an error in your `Error List` panel, at the bottom of the screen.

Double-click on the `'Namespace.Class' does not contain a definition for 'method'` error description. This will automatically bring you to `YourForm.Designer.cs` file and highlight the missing event handler method.

Erase the event handler line. If you double-clicked the form, it will likely be `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Load);`

You're now free to compile again and continue your program.

Comment: But step two got him into this mess in the first place!

Comment: I think the advice is to click on the error message, not the control.

Comment: Click on the error message indeed. Clicking on the control creates a new event handler, clicking on the error message when you remove the method gets you to the handler definition.

Comment: This solution worked as described. I just needed the courage to ignore the code comment "do not modify". ta.speot.is was LOL

Comment: What is the best way to remove the unwanted method? Is there a refactoring action that does what I should have done in the first place?

Comment: @user3076170 AFAIK erasing it manually as I explained is the only way. Even Resharper's "Safe Delete" does not work.